# XmlStreamingMarkupBuilder does not accept binding to the xmlns namespace for version 2.5.7

Tags: xml, groovy

I am using the Groovy `XmlStreamingMarkupBuilder` to build some xml for a jobs monitoring system. However, the namespace is bound to xmlns in the schema I inherited. The parser is throwing an error complaining that I cannot bind to the xmlns explicity. Is there a way to circumvent this problem? Here is the code: If change the xmlns to something else to code works.

```
Object buildJobsXml() {
    markupBuilder.useDoubleQuotes = true
    def jobsXml = markupBuilder.bind{ builder ->
        mkp.xmlDeclaration()
        namespaces << [xmlns:'http://fancy-web-paraphernalia']
        jobs{
            version('3.0')
            jobId('id')
         }
    }
    return  jobsXml
}
```

I was able to set the namespace, but it cascades to every element, I only want it in the outermost element. Here's what I did. I used empty double quotes and that allowed to set the namespace to

```
xmlns:"http://fancy-web-paraphernalia"
```

However, it now appears in all the elements, which I don't want

```
Object buildJobsXml() {
    markupBuilder.useDoubleQuotes = true
    def jobsXml = markupBuilder.bind{
        mkp.xmlDeclaration()
        namespaces << ["":'http://fancy-web-paraphernalia']
        jobs{
            version('3.0')
            jobId('id')
         }
    }
    return  jobsXml
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This works. If there is a better way please post your solution

```
 Object buildJobsXml() {
   markupBuilder.useDoubleQuotes = true
  def jobsXml =  markupBuilder.bind{
    mkp.xmlDeclaration()
    jobs(xmlns:"http://fancy-web-paraphernalia"){
        version('3.0')
        jobId('id')
    }
  }
def result = XmlUtil.serialize(jobsXml)
println "${result}"
```

}